# 'Norm' or 'standard' but in a neutral (or negative) sense

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking to replace the word 'norm' in

> The norm among managers is to use technique X

because technique X is actually bad, and 'norm' suggests a positive value judgment to me. Same with standard.

I tag with 'single-word-requests', but a couple would be fine too.

Comment: “Typical practice” is more neutral.

Comment: I think that is spot on @Xanne. Thank you, I couldn't come up with it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good word in this case is **[default](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/default)**. It can have slightly negative connotations.

Comment: Hah! Now I have 'typical' and 'default' to choose from. Thanks so much.